# How to run Python script from R?

Tags: python, r, powershell, cmd

I'm trying a simple example but it fails:

`system("cmd.exe", input = 'python --version')`

Microsoft Windows [Wersja 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Wszelkie prawa zastrzezone.

C:\Users\cp\Documents\R DATA\LocalAuth>python --version
Nazwa 'python' nie jest rozpoznawana jako polecenie wewnetrzne lub zewnetrzne,
program wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy.

I understand, the cmd should not work there, but when I open:

`system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", input = 'python --version')`

Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\cp\Documents\R DATA\LocalAuth> python --version
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
 the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python --version
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

When I open this console manually it works, but, in properties I see the full path:

`%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3' "`

How can I use it with all these parameters in R? When I try to use it link within system command I get:

Error in "%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command " &  : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

I guess this must work someway: while I enter the dir within command console (cmd.exe) to "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" and type python --version I get a message but with
`system("C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\ python --version")` it doesn't work. Why?

**EDIT**

Found non-elegent solution

```
setwd("C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/")
system(command = 'cmd.exe', input = 'python --version')
```

It works but changes the working dir which is not required.

Comment: `cmd /c C:\folder\python.exe --version`

Comment: Python is not an internal command, and will only run like that if a file with a basename of `python` exists within the current directory or it's parent directory is contained within `%PATH%`. In both cases it's extension must be listed under `%PATHEXT%` or have an entry in the registry to determine what to do with files of that type. Additionally your example requires that you read the output, which means you would need a method to keep the `cmd.exe` window open, the `/K` option does that. `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /K ""C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" --version"` seems more like it.